# Add CSS directly into HTML on a template webpage

Tags: html, css, templates

I have a webpage that is a template from a company that design it for us and we have an admin panel which we can add content to the page.

This normally works fine but there is a specific page that doesn't look great. It has a lot of text on it and we want the background to be a dark brown colour, a gold border around it and the text in bold.

When we are adding content we create a content block and in this, we can add html, I have recently done a very basic course in html. I know normally the page will link to a CSS file which will provide the page style. But I also know you can add the `<style>` tag in and then add CSS directly into the HTML.

This is maybe a long shot but does anyone with any knowledge of template website know if it would work to add the css in this way just to change the background colour and give it a border? I presume I would need to use something like google dev tools to find out what the section names are to identify them in the CSS? According to dev tools the section I want to modify looks like this.

```
<div id="content">
<div class="cs-content-row">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have very limited control, e.g. you can't add a `<style>` tag to the `<head>` or use a custom stylesheet, you can also resort to using inline style, and style individual elements using the `style` attribute.

See example of use;

```
<div style="background:brown; border:1px solid yellow; color:white; font-weight:bold; padding:30px;">Your text here</div>
```

The pros are it overrides the default styling easily, but the downside is you have to re-write code for every element you want to custom style, and if you changed your mind about the colour, you'll have to edit every instance it was used..

Answer (score 0):

You mean normal css into html like this?

```html
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <style>
    body{
      background:red;  
    }
    #content{
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      background:blue;
    }
    .cs-content-row{
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      background:green;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="content">
     <div class="cs-content-row">
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `style` tag but you have to add it between the `<head>` tags of your page.
If your admin panel allows you to update that part of HTML you can do something like that :

According to your HTML description

```html
<head>
    <style>
        #content{
            /* css targeting the div with id attribute equals to 'content' */
        }
        .cs-content-row{
            /* css targeting the div with class attribute equals to 'cs-content-row' */
        }
    </style>
</head>
```